# создание простейшего клиент-серверного приложения на javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Пытаюсь разобраться как работают клиент-серверные приложения. Нигде не могу найти простейший пример на localhost'e, где создается клиент на HTML+JS и тут же сервер на node js. Что-то вроде этого:
**Клиент на HTML+JS открыт в браузере**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => console.log(text));
```

**сервер на Node JS**:

```
const http = require("http");

const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("My first server!");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
```

ожидаю, что при запуске сервера и открытии страницы HTML, в браузере в console.log() придет сообщение

```
My first server!
```

однако, это не работает. в консоли разработчика в браузера получаю различные ошибки

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at index.html:9:9
```

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Прошу помочь разобраться в данном вопросе, желательно с примерами кода!

Comment: Попробуйте 127.0.0.1 заменить на localhost

Comment: Заменил - не работает. А оно в принципе вообще должно работать?

Comment: Здесь смотрите https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-http-client-with-core-http-in-node-js

Comment: Добавь заголовки в ответе сервера `res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8","Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});`

Comment: Спасибо, добавление заголовков помогло!

Comment: На здоровье! :)